# Can a dependent keep COBRA as secondary insurance as well as an (inferior) new employment group insurance?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, dependents, cobra

Details:
The COBRA is for an awesome PPO insurance. Primary subscriber is about to start a new job. Both my child and I are dependents facing high medical and prescription costs in the next few months, and we don't yet know the details of what procedures and will not be covered by the new employer.

The summary of insurance options shows much higher co-insurance percentages both in and out-of-network. We do not know yet which providers will be in-network.

Subsidiary questions:

- Does the employer automatically terminate COBRA as soon as a dependent is covered by a new employer?
- What would be the date of termination be?
- Is it affected by a dependent's disability? We applied for SSA disability eligibility, but child has not yet been declared disabled w/in the first 60 days after the start of COBRA.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the employer automatically terminate COBRA as soon as a dependent is covered by a new employer?

No, COBRA will not be automatically terminated. You can keep COBRA when you get new coverage, and the rules about what it costs or how long it's available don't change, although COB rules dictate that the COBRA plan will automatically be considered secondary. So you can keep your COBRA plan if it makes sense to you.

Although, of course, it makes sense to answer the questions you have in terms of covered procedures and in network providers on your new plan, because it may be the case that your COBRA premium is more than the benefit you'd receive from keeping it.